# Yii2 - datepicker in form displaying 0000-00-00 in database and index page

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am trying to input a start and end date in my yii2 framework form. When I submit it the dates appear as `0000-00-00` :( I have set the dateformat for `yyyy-mm-dd` because i know that this is the dateformat for mySQL (which is the database i am using). What am I doing wrong? :/

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'start_date')->widget(yii\jui\DatePicker::className(),['clientOptions' => ['dateFormat' => 'yyyy-mm-dd']]) ?>
<br><br>
<?= $form->field($model, 'end_date')->widget(yii\jui\DatePicker::className(),['clientOptions' => ['dateFormat' => 'yyyy-mm-dd']]) ?>
```

Comment: You have to debug your code, try a var_dump() when you get the form data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the *clientOpitons.dateFormat* value directly, you can use the widget's `dateFormat' option to set it.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'start_date')
    ->widget(yii\jui\DatePicker::class,[
        'dateFormat' =>  => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        'options' => []
    ]
) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'end_date')
    ->widget(yii\jui\DatePicker::class,[
        'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    ]
) ?>
```

You can find more options on how to set the date in the [date-picker documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-jui/doc/api/2.0/yii-jui-datepicker#$dateFormat-detail).

In the documentation for `dateFormat` it says:

> If not set the default value will be taken from Yii::$app->formatter->dateFormat.

My guess is that the value you are setting directly using `clientOptions` is getting overwritten by the default taken from the application formatter.